# libpd library Low latency support for video?

Tags: java, android, latency, low-latency, libpd

I recently found the libpd library which can be used when developing applications for Android.  As I have understood, it can be used for example music related projects where low latency is required.

My question is if the library can be used with video as well? I need several video clips to be able to, on various Android devices, play simultaneously with as low latency as possible.

Library:
https://github.com/libpd/pd-for-android

Some other source:
http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2012/07/why-music-apps-will-sound-better-than-ever-in-android-jelly-bean/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the short answer is "no".

`libpd` encapsulates the audio (and message) domain of "Pure Data".

for *video*, you will most likely be better of using a native solution.

(afaik, none of the graphics externals for Pd has been ported to android yet).